# How do I tell eclipse to ignore files not related to the project

Tags: eclipse, macos

ecilpse is giving warnings because it doesn't understand some files that are not related to the project such as the .DS_Store files:

[image]

Comment: You can also just delete the `.DS_Store` files, but if you use `Finder` to look at the folder it will put them back!

Answer (score 7):

These files can be ignored on a per-project basis...

First, right-click the project and open the properties and go to Resource Filters:

[image]

Then simply add an exclusion rule like this:

[image]

You can also use this for hidden svn/git files and folders that may be causing you problems.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above didn't help me.
I use a solution from [Egit: Set gitignore to ignore all eclipse project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114228/egit-set-gitignore-to-ignore-all-eclipse-project-files)

Add in project .gitignore file the code

```
# Mac
.DS_Store
```