# Egit: Set gitignore to ignore all eclipse project files

Tags: java, eclipse, git, gradle, gitignore

I have a project up on github and I want to remove all eclipse related files from it and allow people who clone it to use any ide they want. Here is the project: https://github.com/vedi0boy/Archipelo

What would I have to put in my gitignore? I'm still very new to the whole version control manager thing so you don't have to tell me exactly what to put but maybe explain how it works and what to be careful about so that it will still work.

By the way, it uses gradle so I would also like it so that the gradle related files remain untouched since cloners will need them to build the project and I plan to remove 'APIs' folder and just use gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For excluding configuration files you have to configure `.gitignore` to something as follows:

```
# Eclipse
.classpath
.project
.settings/

# Intellij
.idea/
*.iml
*.iws

# Mac
.DS_Store

# Maven
log/
target/
```

And, only after this, you have to push your project because now you have to push your configuration to the remote repo.

And you can not delete it locally and push. You have to delete it from remote repo only:

> git rm --cached .project

For a directory:

> git rm --cached -r target

Answer (score 1):

One of my `.gitignore` files looks like this:

```
/bin
/.classpath
/.project
/.settings
/target
```

You can look at other projects at e.g. GitHub to let you inspire what you might want to put into your `.gitignore`, e.g.:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/.gitignore
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/blob/master/.gitignore

However, I think my example above should be sufficient to start with.

Comment: I will use a combination of your answer and the other 2. Thanks for your help. I decided to accept nazar's because it will help others with different ide's too.

Answer (score 1):

Add all the eclipse files to the .gitignore and, to remove them from the remote repository, you will have to

```
git rm (-r) --cached eclipseProjectFile
```

The above command will remove the file from the repo, but not from your machine.

Comment: Thanks for this! But can't I just configure it on my machine and then do an override on the git? I've done it before.

Comment: @vedi0boy I believe overriding like that is considered bad practice, and its preferable to do the remove command as it is nicely logged in the history of the git repo.

Answer (score 0):

1 -     create .gitignore file on your GIT project root direcotry (where you have typed "git init" (near .git directory) ). With content of nazar_art noticed or you can add some other pattern for ignore.

2 -    `git rm -r --cached file_1 file_n directory_1 directory_n` ...

3 -    `git commit -m "removed some files and directories from remote repo and created gitignore :))"`

4 -   `git push -u origin --all` (this will synch all branch of your remote (origin) repo) or you can type  git push [remote] [branch]

*i know it is late. but may be helpful somebody who just beginning*

Answer (score 0):

This is general answer to ignore any file extension from git staging.

1. In Eclipse go to windows->preferences->git->ignore resources (you can simply search "ignore resources").
2. Check any class extensions that you want to avoid staging in git staging area.
3. If you do not find your extension there, you have the option to add any extension that you need to ignore.